# Ubuntu 14.04 "azureuser" exists - and I did not create it

Tags: ubuntu, users, pam

I just logged into an Ubuntu 14.04 instance and in the home folder there is a user "azureuser" (yes, this is an Azure VM) with four items in it:

.ssh (folder)
.bash_logout (file)
.bashrc (file)
.profile (file)

This user does not exist on any of my other Ubuntu VMs including the server that I created this image from.

Here is the .profile contents:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists

if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

While I didn't use the "quick create" option I did create this VM using the new Preview Portal and that might account for the creation of that username.

Does anyone know where this came from and/or if it's something that needs to be there?

Comment: Perhaps this is the only VM where you used the Quick Create option, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553621/determine-which-user-created-an-azure-ubuntu-linux-server-with-quick-create).

Comment: Nope, I don't use quick create. But it seems that it is not a "necessary" user so I deleted that user, and have no issues. Still not sure where it came from as I created the VM from an image of another VM that does not have that "azureuser" on it. Thank you!